# Can I create link as post to 3rd party site and open in new tab?

Tags: jquery, html, post

I'm trying to create a list of links. When clicking on the link I want to open up a 3rd party site and log in with stored credentials.

Basically, I want it to function just like an ordinary link to any site except that the `POST` values should be sent and have it open up in another tab.

I've done research that seems to show that there are JavaScript and jQuery methods of doing this, but I'm unsure exactly how it should be structured.

Comment: Good point. How do sites like lastpass and awardwallet pull this off?

Comment: Outside the browser. They're downloadable applications.

Comment: @meagar: I’d be curious to know what sort of layers you think prevent this. All I can think of is the cross-origin restriction(s), which do not apply to, for example, form POSTs. It is this lack of restriction that makes Cross-Site Request Forgery possible.

Comment: @meagar: Sure you can. Same way those sites let you log in to themselves -- HTML forms.

Comment: I always thought (but obviously never tested) that browsers prevented you from programatically submitting forms where the action violated same-origin policy, I'm apparently pretty wrong. **However**. Most websites (not your browser) will prevent this anyways with a CSRF token. The answers below will fail on most websites for this reason if not specifically because the browser prevents this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. Use the `action`, `method`, and `target` attributes of the `form` element:

```
<form action="https://www.3rd-party.example/" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="administrator">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="hunter2">
    <input type="submit" value="Log in to 3rd party with administrator/hunter2">
</form>
```

If you don’t want it to be a button, you can use CSS to style it to look like a link.

Comment: Note that this will fail on any website built by anybody who knows what their doing, unless they *explicitly* want to allow you to do this. CSRF tokens are an accepted best practice, and they're given to you automatically by most modern frameworks. Their purpose is explicitly to prevent this sort of thing.

Comment: Accepted because this was the simplest approach. This is strictly for internal use and will not be exposed to the public so I'm not too concerned about security.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to have the link submit a hidden form that points to that 3rd party site.

```
<form id="login" action="[THE SITE'S LOGIN PAGE]" method="post" target="_blank">
    <!-- HYPOTHETICAL NAME/VALUES -->
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="bob">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="secret">
</form>

<a href="javascript:document.forms['login'].submit();">Log in</a>
```

The input fields will obviously have to be filled in in a way that the 3rd party site will understand.

Explanation: You can't send POST data with normal links, so JS is required (or instead of a link and JS, you could use a form button). Forms don't suffer the same restrictions as AJAX, so they're an ideal choice. The `target="_blank"` causes the site to open in a new tab.